# How do I make jQuery-UI datepicker show up in the center of my screen?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Right now the datepicker's position is determined via inline css that is being added by javascript via the jQuery-UI framework. I'd love to have the datepicker in the center of the screen instead of being located based on where my trigger is.

How do I override this positioning being generated by jQuery with something of my own? I even have a jQuery script to center a div in the center of a screen but it's still not working due to the script being overwritten by jquery-ui's.

Here's the inline code generated:

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker 
  ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-  clearfix ui-corner-all 
  ui-datepicker-multi ui-datepicker-multi-2" style="width: 34em; 
  position: absolute; left: 349px; top: 453px; z-index: 1; display: block; ">
```

Here is a jQuery function to center a div on the screen:

```
//center div on screen
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
}
```

Which is called by by: `$('.ui-datepicker').center();`

What would be the code to use this function to center the `.ui-datepicker` div on the center of the screen?

**EDIT:** here's the website: http://univiaje.spin-demo.com/

- click on one of the links below the red background in the sidebar, a window should open
- click on the calendar icon
- **fail :(**

Answer (score 20):

HTML, CSS solution

HTML:

```
<div id="datepicker-container">
  <div id="datepicker-center">
    <div id="datepicker"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#datepicker-container{
  text-align:center;
}
#datepicker-center{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

You can try to position fixed the inline datepicker in the center of the screen, with the following:

```
#ui-datepicker-div{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 9999;

    -webkit-transform   : translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform      : translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform       : translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform           : translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

then show it on open and hide it on close/selection.

I tried to find a plugin that already do this for me, and I found this one: https://codecanyon.net/item/date-picker-in-fullscreen-jquery-plugin/20224980 which is based on Bootstrap Date Picker, may be worth to check it out

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in a `beforeShow` callback in which you do something like `$(this).css(...)`. See here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShow

EDIT:

If you want to use your `center` function, just do this (note I was targeting the wrong element before):

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
  this.css("position","absolute");
  this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
  this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
  return this;
}

$(selector).datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        // $(inst).center() // not sure if this works
        $('.ui-datepicker').center() // this should work
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input man. Still doesn't want to work, I've edited my original post and added a link to the site itself

Comment: Sorry, I was targeting the wrong element. Not sure if `inst` will work. Show me your site and I'll take a look.

Comment: You need to add that beforeShow to the original binding – `$('#date_from, #date_to').datepicker({...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use datepicker's `beforeShow` property to set the callback where you can write your code to center the datepicker on the page. Try this

```
$(selector).datepicker({ 
    beforeShow: function(picker, inst) { 
        //Code to show the datepicker in the center.
    } 
});
```

Comment: You can call your plugin in beforeShow callback by selecting the datepicker div.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. Here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/1603381

Comment: use `beforeShow` and not `onShow`. In your code you have used `onShow`.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
#ui-datepicker-div {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

Adjust the top and left margins byy half the height and width. Make sure this CSS is before the jQuery UI CSS.

Comment: The javascript overwrites any css because it's inline. Even if I use !important it will still get overwritten.

Comment: Add the CSS via jQuery after the inline css is generated.

Comment: more straightforward: .ui-datepicker-inline { margin: 0 auto; }

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but still high on Google. That's why I answer.

**Find this in your datepicker js file.**

```
inst.dpDiv.css({position: ($.datepicker._inDialog && $.blockUI ?
    "static" : (isFixed ? "fixed" : "absolute")), display: "none",
    left: offset.left + "px", top: offset.top + "px"});
```

**And change it with:**

```
inst.dpDiv.css({position: ($.datepicker._inDialog && $.blockUI ?
    "static" : (isFixed ? "fixed" : "absolute")), display: "none",
    left: "50%", top: "25%", transform: "translateX(-50%)"});
```

Then you'll have the box centered on the screen 25% from the top.

Answer (score 0):

Magnus's solution works fine for me only if adjusted with `!important`:

```
#ui-datepicker-div{
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 50% !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    z-index: 9999 !important;

    -webkit-transform   : translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) !important;
    -moz-transform      : translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) !important;
    -ms-transform       : translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) !important;
    transform           : translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know tables are a bit of a "no-no" these days, but i found it sorted the problem for me:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:40%">
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="myDatePicker">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:40%">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```