# place jquery datepicker on center of page

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

```
<input id='cpdate' type='text'>
```

I want to place the `datepicker` on center of page horizontally and `120px` form top vertically.

```
$("#cpdate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
    , beforeShow: function() {
        $('.ui-datepicker').css({
            width: '160px'
            , position: 'fixed'
            , left: 'calc(100vw - 80px)'
            , top: '120px'
        });
    }
});
```

Doesn't work. Date picker still appears inside `#cpdate` parent (right sidebar);

Yes, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842425/how-do-i-make-jquery-ui-datepicker-show-up-in-the-center-of-my-screen) but it doesn't work for me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one `class` to your `CSS` like this:

```
.ui-datepicker {
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed !important;
  left: calc(50vw - 40px) !important;
  top: 120px !important; 
}
```

**[Online demo (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/mhwdr2na/)**